# python list concatenation with add function used

Tags: python, concatenation

I just realized a problem, when I try to use "+" in a list concatenation situation.

For example I can do:

```
print([[1] + [5]* n for n in range(1, 4)])
>>> [[1, 5], [1, 5, 5], [1, 5, 5, 5]]
```

But if I switch the sequence of the add function:

```
print([[5] * n for n in range(1, 4) + [1]])
```

I won't get:

```
>>> [[5, 1], [5, 5, 1], [5, 5, 5, 1]]
```

Instead I got:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'`

Is there anyway to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add it to the list that you're manipulating, not the range you're iterating through. Also, if you either do addition, then multiplication (here we're doing multiplication, then addition), you would have to surround the first statement since Python orders operations according to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

```
print([[5] * n + [1] for n in range(1, 4)])
```

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 Happy to help, don't forget to accept it after the time period of 10 minutes :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are doing this operation:

```py
range(1, 4) + [1]
```

Which doesn't mean anything in this case.

You have to do the `+ [1]` right after the `[5] * n` as in:

```py
print([[5]*n+[1] for n in range(1, 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick as contributors already have answered

```
[[5] * n + [1] for n in range(1, 4)]
```

But in your solution type of range(1, 4) will be , if you want to do some list operations on it like concatenation then you should do like:

```
list(range(1, 4)) + [1]
```

Comment: thanks, I don't think `list(range(1, 4))` has anything to do with this.

Comment: Agree, it was just to point out if you want to do any operations to range then we need to convert it to list first.